# Generate release_note.md when distributing by fastlane on app center

Tags: azure, git-commit, fastlane, appcenter

- I have one repo at azure, and now using fastlane at terminal to build and distribute app to AppCenter.
- Can I excute fastlane command to generate `release_note.md`, the file will contains branch name, and last git commits.

Thanks for your support!

Comment: Can you clarify? I'm not sure what you are asking. Where do you want to execute those commands? Why can't you execute them?

Comment: Thanks, that is just my question. Actually, I just were curious. When build ipa app and submit to app center or firebase, I was curious that we have any ways to generate `release_note.md` without doing manually. Release_note is used to note the release tasks

Comment: What should it contain? How should it be generated? Can you generate it locally? This questions lacks focus or is asking many questions at once. Is generating the file the problem? Or how to do this in fastlane (if so, what specifically; can you run other commands in fastlane already)? What is the format of the file? The expected content?

Comment: Thank for your advice, maybe I should research more and come back later.